# Formatting Diff output in Shell Script

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I'm currently using (diff -q directory1 directory2) to output the files in each directory that are different and printing them to a table in html. 
Current output: "Files directory1/file1 and directory2/file2 differ"

What I want: "file1 has changed"

I do not want to use comm or sort the files because other applications are pulling from the files and are sensitive to ordering. Any idea on how to get this done?

Comment: Have you tried anything to get what you want?

Comment: @doveice : i am wondering why you didn't accept any answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to grep diff output for file that differ then use awk to print file name with your new format

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2 | grep "differ" | awk '{print $2 "has changed"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
diff -q $file1 $file2 | awk '{print $2 " has changed"}'
```